# Django tests pass on local environment and fail on Travis CI

Tags: django, travis-ci

I have the following project structure

[image: Project structure]

when I run `./manage.py test` the result is:

```
./manage.py test
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
..
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 0.056s

OK
Destroying test database for alias 'default'...
```

But when i push to github, the build of Travis CI get the foollowing error:

```
$ python manage.py test
.E
======================================================================
ERROR: test_import (core.tests.test_iodb.ImportTestCase)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/travis/build/Sidon/work-at-olist/core/tests/test_iodb.py", line 14, in test_import
    channel = Channel.objects.get(name='Test1')
  File "/home/travis/virtualenv/python3.6.2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/travis/virtualenv/python3.6.2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 380, in get
    self.model._meta.object_name
core.models.DoesNotExist: Channel matching query does not exist.
```

In /home/travis/build/Sidon/work-at-olist/core/tests/test_iodb.py:

```
from core.models import Category, Channel
from core.utils import iocsv

class ImportTestCase(TestCase):
    categs1 = ....

    def test_import(self):
        iocsv.imp_categories('test1.csv', 'Test1')
   ===> channel = Channel.objects.get(name='Test1') # Here the error
```